# how to get submitted value with CSJS on xPage?

Tags: javascript, xpages

I can get popup menu item clicked by using SSJS in onItemClick event:

```
context.getSubmittedValue()
```

But how do I get item clicked by using CSJS in same onItemClick event?
This is not seem to be helpful:

```
thisEvent.target.id
```

and this one doesn't return anything:

```
thisEvent.target.innerHTML
```

Here is my xPage:

```
<xe:popupMenu id="popupMenu1">
    <xe:this.treeNodes>
        <xe:basicLeafNode label="menu item 1" submitValue="mi1"></xe:basicLeafNode>
        <xe:basicLeafNode label="menu item 2" submitValue="mi2"></xe:basicLeafNode>
    </xe:this.treeNodes>
    <xp:eventHandler event="onItemClick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="complete">
        <xe:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:print(context.getSubmittedValue());}]]></xe:this.action>
        <xe:this.script><![CDATA[alert(thisEvent.target.innerHTML);]]></xe:this.script>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xe:popupMenu>
```

I need to get any info that would help me to identify which item was clicked in CSJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the onClick event of each basicLeafNode to determine what was clicked in CSJS.

Here's an example how to use the onClick event of the basicLeafNode.

If you need to execute SSJS code you can trigger the click event on a hidden button that has an event handler that runs your SSJS code.

Note that when you add onClick event to a basicLeafNode it overwrites the onItemClick event: [Cannot get XPages toolbar onItemClick event to execute when basicLeafNode contains onClick event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37867543/cannot-get-xpages-toolbar-onitemclick-event-to-execute-when-basicleafnode-contai)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xp:button value="Label" id="button1">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="false">
            <xp:this.script><![CDATA[
            XSP.openMenu(thisEvent,#{javascript:getComponent('popupMenu1').getMenuCtor()});
            ]]></xp:this.script>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
    <xe:popupMenu id="popupMenu1">
        <xe:this.treeNodes>
            <xe:basicLeafNode label="menu item 1" submitValue="mi1">
                <xe:this.onClick><![CDATA[document.getElementById("#{id:mi1Event}").click();]]></xe:this.onClick>
            </xe:basicLeafNode>
            <xe:basicLeafNode label="menu item 2" submitValue="mi2">
                <xe:this.onClick><![CDATA[document.getElementById("#{id:mi2Event}").click();]]></xe:this.onClick>
            </xe:basicLeafNode>
        </xe:this.treeNodes>

        <xp:eventHandler event="onItemClick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
            <xe:this.action>
                <![CDATA[#{javascript:
                print("onItemClick event running"); // Will not run!
            }]]></xe:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xe:popupMenu>


    <xp:button value="_mi1" id="mi1Event" style="display:none;">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" immediate="false" onComplete="console.log('onComplete of mi1 running');" refreshId="popupMenu1">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:print("ssjs code for mi1 running");}]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>

    <xp:button value="_mi2" id="mi2Event" style="display:none;">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" immediate="false" onComplete="alert('onComplete of mi2 running');" refreshId="popupMenu1">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:print("ssjs code for mi2 running");}]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>

</xp:view>
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to proceed onItemClick ServerSide code first. Then depending on item clicked I need to refresh appropriate item on form in eventHandler onComplete event. So here is where I need CSJS to get element clicked

Comment: I updated my answer with a method to execute SSJS code using the onClick of the basicLeafNode

Answer (score 1):

As you wrote in your comment, you want to execute SSJS code first and only later CSJS code. Unfortunately, eventHandler executes CSJS always first.

Use `view.postScript()` in SSJS code to execute code on client side after code ran on server. Your eventHandler would look like this:

```
<xp:eventHandler
        event="onItemClick"
        submit="true"
        refreshMode="complete">
        <xe:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
            var value = context.getSubmittedValue();
            print(value);
            view.postScript('alert("' + value + '");');
            }]]></xe:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
```

You can call a function on client side this way and use the selected value as a parameter:
`view.postScript('yourClientSideFunction("' + value + '");');`

Comment: Thank you Knut.. I know about view.postscript.. It does work. But I will use jthomas solution below.